# How to input 5 numbers and determine the order? SWI-PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Create PROLOG rules that will perform the following operations based on user input:

Get the number of integers to use:

1. Find the highest number (‘High’)
2. Find the lowest number (‘Low’)
3. Find the second-highest number (‘Second High’)
4. Find the second-lowest number (‘Second Low’)

The expected output is:

1. Enter operation: ‘Second high’
2. Enter number of inputs: 5
3. Enter number: 46
4. Enter number: 1
5. Enter number: 234
6. Enter number: 67
7. Enter number: 8
8. Result: 67

Comment: What have you tried? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it like this. RPN is easier to implement and use, too.

Here is an example calculator:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

rpn :-
    prompt(_, '(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) '),
    repl([]).

repl(Stack) :-
    get_token(T),
    repl(T, Stack).

get_token(T) :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Input),
    (   Input == end_of_file
    ->  T = quit
    ;   (   phrase(( whites, token(T), whites ), Input)
        ->  true
        ;   T = error(Input)
        )
    ).

token(number(N)) --> number(N).
token(print_stack) --> "p".
token(highest) --> "H".
token(second_highest) --> "h".
token(lowest) --> "L".
token(second_lowest) --> "l".
token(clear) --> "c".
token(help) --> "?".
token(quit) --> "q" | "quit" | "exit".

repl(quit, _) :-
    format("Goodbye!~n").
repl(error(E), Stack) :-
    format("Bad input: `~s'~n", [E]),
    repl(Stack).
repl(help, Stack) :-
    format("Add a number to the list or type:~n"),
    format("   'H' to show highest number~n"),
    format("   'h' to show second-highest number~n"),
    format("   'L' to show lowest number~n"),
    format("   'l' to show second-lowest number~n"),
    format("   'p' to print the stack, top to bottom~n"),
    format("   'c' to clear the stack~n"),
    format("   '?' to show this help~n"),
    format("then press Enter~n"),
    repl(Stack).
repl(print_stack, Stack) :-
    reverse(Stack, S),
    forall(member(X, S), format("~w~n", [X])),
    repl(Stack).
repl(highest, Stack) :-
    max_list(Stack, X),
    format("Highest: ~w~n", [X]),
    repl(Stack).
repl(second_highest, Stack) :-
    sort(0, @>=, Stack, [_,X|_]), % this keeps duplicates!
    format("Second highest: ~w~n", [X]),
    repl(Stack).
repl(lowest, Stack) :-
    min_list(Stack, X),
    format("Lowest: ~w~n", [X]),
    repl(Stack).
repl(second_lowest, Stack) :-
    sort(0, @>=, Stack, [_,X|_]),
    format("Second lowest: ~w~n", [X]),
    repl(Stack).
repl(clear, _) :-
    repl([]).
repl(number(N), Stack) :-
    repl([N|Stack]).
```

It goes like this:

```
?- rpn.
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) 46
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) 1
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) 234
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) 67
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) 8
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) ?
Add a number to the list or type:
   'H' to show highest number
   'h' to show second-highest number
   'L' to show lowest number
   'l' to show second-lowest number
   'p' to print the stack, top to bottom
   'c' to clear the stack
   '?' to show this help
then press Enter
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) h
Second highest: 67
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) H
Highest: 234
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) p
46
1
234
67
8
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) c
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) p
(number or command followed by Enter; ? for help) quit
Goodbye!
true.
```

This is a better interface.